# Serialized Publishing failure at Deploying state

Tags: web8.5, publishing, deployer, publishingfailed

When serialized content is published out like

```
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type=\"Embedded\" componentURI=\"tcm:444-444444\" templateURI=\"tcm:444-4444-32\">
```

publishing is getting failed at "Deploying" state on Deployer.

Please help if anyone have encountered the same.

```
at com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer.transform(TCDLDefaultTransformer.java:93) ... 21 common frames omitted Caused by: com.tridion.transformer.TCDLTransformerException: Invalid tag attributestype=\"Embedded\" componentURI=\"tcm:404-183444\" templateURI=\"tcm:404-1924-32\" Source (408) :<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type=\"Embedded\" componentURI=\"tcm:404-183444\" templateURI=\"tcm:404-1924-32\"> 

Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Invalid tag attributestype=\"Embedded\" componentURI=\"tcm:404-183444\" templateURI=\"tcm:404-1924-32\" at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLAttributeParser.processAttributes(TCDLAttributeParser.java:47) at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLParser.parseTagBody(TCDLParser.java:102) ... 25 common frames omitted 

2020-04-24 16:07:02,493 ERROR CommandQueuePoller - Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-6918966-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-6918966-66560', properties={}} reason: Could not transform tcdl file /opt/apps/sdl/dsitw/_data/deployer/service/binary/Binaries/Zip/tcm_0-6918966-66560.Content/Pages/_ia/devtest/transformed/ddynfootjson.json 2020-04-24 16:07:03,438 ERROR StepActor - Step 'PageDeploy' for 'tcm:0-6918967-66560' can NOT retry
```

Comment: Can you please mention which version of tridion you're using and enable log level to debug or tace on the deployer side, share logs as well.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stackexchange, plese update your question with deployer error logs?

Comment: at com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer.transform(TCDLDefaultTransformer.java:93)
 ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.transformer.TCDLTransformerException: Invalid tag attributestype=\"Embedded\" componentURI=\"tcm:404-183444\" templateURI=\"tcm:404-1924-32\" Source (408) :<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type=\"Embedded\" componentURI=\"tcm:404-183444\" templateURI=\"tcm:404-1924-32\">

Comment: Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Invalid tag attributestype=\"Embedded\" componentURI=\"tcm:404-183444\" templateURI=\"tcm:404-1924-32\"
 at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLAttributeParser.processAttributes(TCDLAttributeParser.java:47)
 at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLParser.parseTagBody(TCDLParser.java:102)
 ... 25 common frames omitted

Comment: 2020-04-24 16:07:02,493 ERROR CommandQueuePoller - Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-6918966-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-6918966-66560', properties={}} reason: Could not transform tcdl file /opt/apps/sdl/dsitw/_data/deployer/service/binary/Binaries/Zip/tcm_0-6918966-66560.Content/Pages/_ia/devtest/transformed/ddynfootjson.json
2020-04-24 16:07:03,438 ERROR StepActor - Step 'PageDeploy' for 'tcm:0-6918967-66560' can NOT retry

Comment: SDL Web 8.5 is the version.

Comment: Can you also update the encoding used for your publication target? Do you have the same error when you change the target language to "None" and check tcdl config.xml on the deployer side chek target language is set to which language.